# SQL Query Not Displaying All Results

Tags: ee2, sql

I am setting up a search by author section on the blog for my website. I have all the code set up correct, and people are showing up! However, not everyone is showing up. When I run the SQL Query below, I am short a couple of results. When I move a member from Group 6 to Group 1, she shows up.

Am I missing something here?

```
<h1 style="font-size:24px;font-weight:normal;color:#72736F;border-bottom: 1px dotted #999;">Search by Author</h1>

{exp:query sql="SELECT* 
  FROM exp_members 
  WHERE group_id = '1' OR group_id = '6'
  AND total_entries != 0
  AND in_authorlist = 'y'
"}
  <a href="{site_url}wcrealtors_blogs/author/{member_id}" class="blogimg">
    <img src="{site_url}/images/avatars/{avatar_filename}" class="imgblogauthorbar"/>
  </a>
{/exp:query}
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There should be a space between your select statement and your all field list term:

```
SELECT *
```

but past that, this is definitely a correctly structured query. When you visit the

```
CP Home -> Members -> Member Groups -> Edit Member Group
```

page of your Super Admin group, are Super Admins set to yes for this option?

```
Include Members in PUBLISH page multi-author list?
```

Comment: I added the space, and nothing changed. However, the author was not listed in the PUBLISH page multi-author list! Worked like a charm! Thank you, thank you!

Comment: I hope my answer pointed you in the right direction, and glad you got it down!

Comment: It sure did! Thank you so much. Exactly what I needed!!